# JSF 2 - How to destroy a session-scoped bean

Tags: jsf-2

How can I destroy a session-scoped bean?

The purpose of this would be to control the lifetime of the bean so it only lives when a tab in the web application is active. (Using Ajax Based Tab Navigation in the webapp)

Is there a better way to do that? (Custom Scoped Beans?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Session scoped** bean is created on first `HttpRequest` involving this bean. Destroyed when `session` is invalidated. You can also destroy it manually by removing it from the `HttpSession`, or `sessionMap` (get through `FacesContext`).

The fact is that it's **illogical** to create **Session scoped** bean which will live only during the tab view. For this exact purpose defining **Custom scoped** bean will be better, but think about it first:

- Why do you need such functionality ? Because of memory ?

Well it could be pretty tricky, imagine user just switching between the tabs pretty often and you are recreating the bean over and over. Even worse what if you **fetch data from DB** in `constructor` or `@PostConstruct`. It won't be really efficient.

My opinion is that you should forget about it (unless you need it for some other purposes) and pick a **View scoped** bean. This bean gets initialized after accessing the view and lives till you don't switch to another view - so no DB fetching on each tab switch (still same view). IMO it's better to fetch huge data once than eg. 15 times... If you don't fetch any data, then go definitely for **View scoped**. But that's just my opinion as I said.

If you can't afford **View scoped**, go for **Custom scoped** bean, but definitely not **Session scoped**.

Further reading for you : [BalusC on JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Hope it helped !

Comment: A session bean is created when it is requested the first time and not automatically when the session is created.

Comment: @Matt Handy yes sorry, don't know what I was thinking about when writing that, such a mistake ... Thumbs up for pointing out. Is it fine now ?

Comment: No problem. I would not use the session scope here.

Comment: Thanks @Fallup, But If I only use AJAX navigation than there's no real difference between View and Session Scopes.. Right?

Comment: @Ben If you are considering only switching between tabs then no. But if you leave the `view` where are your tabs, then `View scoped` get destroyed but `Session scoped` will still persist.

Comment: @MattHandy I know why session scope is not good for me (took me time, I know :-) )
When I use Server State Saving Method, The Server has a state queue of about ~20 sessions. 
Say I have 21 tabs and I go sequentially over all of them and then return to the first 1, I will receive the view expired exception. This is not such a far fetched example. If you have 3 tabs, iterate of 2 them 20 times and then go back to the third one, you will receive the same exception. Being able to clean the session on tab change will avoid this problem.